# In The Dresden Files, is Harry still beholden to the White Council?

Tags: the-dresden-files

Is Harry Dresden still a member of the White Council and still constrained by their laws, subject to their justice?

In the latest novels he seems to still care about what the council thinks but it seems to me that he shouldn't, seeing as what he is now.

Comment: AFAIK, it isn't entirely clear.  I believe it's been mentioned in the book that there has never been a Knight who is also a Wizard.

Answer (score 6):

The White Council enforces their laws towards **all** mortal wizards, regardless their knowledge, awareness, age or connections. So, my understanding is that shall Dresden violate any of the laws of magic, he would earn attention of the Council's wardens.

As for the other part of the question, it has not been explicitly implied that Dresden loses his status within the Council by accepting Mab's offering  (I haven't read the latest book yet, however).  In "Changes", senior council member Blackstaff notes and comments on Harry's status without any implications - so, I presume, Dresden is still considered member of the Council, with Warden role.

As of the end of Cold Days, assuming the Gatekeeper is as good as his word, paperwork has been filed to reinstate Dresden's status as a wizard of the white council. This implies that Dresden is once again playing by their rules.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. With complications.

Harry's situation might have some resemblances to dual-citizenship. He is a member of the White Council. He is also a member of Mab's Unseelie Court. He is beholden to the laws of both and whatever additional restrictions his positions within those two organizations entail (Warden of Council, Knight of Winter, and even The Warden of Demonreach).

Mab may be the biggest "claim" on him, but she probably doesn't want to override all his other bindings. Doing so would be counter to her nature, would remove him from other potential resources, and besides, *he's* the one who has to dance through it all, not her. It might make her smile, even.

Now, the Council may be more reluctant to pester Harry about little things, considering what he's shacked up with (this may *also* make Mab smile). That said, if they consider him a rogue wizard, they will arrange to take him out. Period. Mab would not even defend him or make a fuss unless something else was at stake; the Knight is supposed to be able to take care of itself, and Harry being stupid enough to anger the Council or weak enough to fall to them would just tell her she needs a better Knight.

Answer (score 1):

In the novel *Cold Days* Harry Dresden encounters

> The Gatekeeper

when he visits

> The Outer Gates

During Harry's conversation with this character, Harry requests assistance to deal with

> The Enemy, who has been driving so much of the plot of the whole series.

The other character is unable to assist Harry with anything other than knowledge (though that turns out to be useful).  When Harry presses him,

> The Gatekeeper

tells Harry he will also notify the Council of Harry's survival, of his continuing resistance towards Mab's power's corrupting influence, and will handle the necessary paperwork.

In short, yes, I expect Harry is still a member of the Council.  I similarly expect that, while serving under Mab's orders, Harry will not be permitted to continue as a Warden.  He certainly hasn't (as of *Skin Game*) been wearing the cloak or discharging any of his duties.

Perhaps this will be clarified in the next book, *Peace Talks*.